# Topological classification of (classical, Abelian) vortices on a lattice

Tags: topology, topological-field-theory, lattice-model, vortex, lattice-gauge-theory

Consider the XY model on the square lattice. A field configuration $\theta$ is specified by an element of the Abelian group $\mathbb{R}/2\pi \simeq U(1)$ at each vertex of the lattice. The gradient of this field is
$$(\mathrm{d}\theta)_{ij} := \theta_j - \theta_i,$$
where $\mathrm{d}$ is the lattice exterior derivative and $i,j$ are two vertices bounding a single edge. Note that the difference here is taken in $\mathbb{R}/2\pi$. Then for each plaquette $p$ with sequential corners $i,j,k,l$, we have
$$(\mathrm{d}^2\theta)_{p} := (\theta_j-\theta_i) + (\theta_k-\theta_j) + (\theta_l - \theta_k) + (\theta_i - \theta_l) \in \mathbb{Z} \,\,(\text{mod } 2\pi)$$
Actually, it can only be $0,\pm 1$, if for each difference we take $\theta_j - \theta_i \in [-\pi,\pi)$, and the sum is taken in $\mathbb{R}$: the result is zero if we take all sums mod $2\pi$.

My primary question is, how exactly do I formalize the fact that this quantity is an integer mod $2\pi$ and not zero? My only thought is that
$$(\mathrm{d}^2\theta)(p) = (\mathrm{d}\theta)(\partial p)$$
where $\partial$ denotes boundary and somehow this defines a map $S^1 \to U(1)$ and therefore a homotopy class, but I'm struggling to make this explicit. Non-trivial solutions of $\mathrm{d}^2 = 0$ in the continuum are only possible for singular field configurations, but these vortices are topological on the lattice in some well defined sense that I am not understanding.

As a follow up question, if I replace $\mathbb{R}/2\pi$ by $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (a clock model) will I also get $\mathbb{Z}_n$ vortices? In that case there is no notion of a homotopically non-trivial map $S^1 \to \mathbb{Z}_n$, but perhaps there is a discrete generalization of homotopy that applies?

Comment: I’m not sure these vortices are topological in a well-defined sense except in the continuum limit

Comment: @JahanClaes but they are certainly quantized, and in Monte Carlo simulations they are precisely the vortices responsible for the KT transition, so I don't understand how they can be non-topological.

Comment: They are just not well-defined. How do you know the winding of a vortex? You pretend that in between the lattice sites the field variables $\theta$ interpolate between the value on the lattice sites. This is fine, except when $|\theta_i-\theta_j|\approx\pi$ in which case it is ambiguous. This goes away in the continuum limit, where you enforce continuity.

Most Monte Carlo simulations will be at low enough temperatures that this ambiguous case is unlikely to occur (the ambiguous case has high energy) and so you'll always approximately see the continuum limit version of the problem.

Comment: Most analyses of the KT transition I've seen consider perturbations about low-energy configurations, so they never see this ambiguous case either. Certainly for low enough energies, you should be near the continuum limit and be able to define a continuum winding number

Comment: @JahanClaes, I don't understand, the procedure I defined above does compute the winding numbers and is the standard method used in Monte Carlo simulations. Furthermore, in Abelian lattice gauge theory with 1-form gauge fields one obtains the same behavior for each volume, which are the lattice magnetic monopoles, see e.g. [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321377901298)

Comment: This is slightly different contextually but should be quite closely related: one can define the Hopf fibration with discrete spaces, see [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01223516).

Comment: Maybe a simpler way to say what I'm saying is: I agree you can always define a winding number via your formula above, where you just take the discrete exterior derivative. But I don't think this is "topological" in the sense you want, because a small change $\theta_i\rightarrow \theta_i+\epsilon$ can change the winding number by an integer amount when $|\theta_i-\theta_j|\approx\pi$.

Comment: The winding number is topological in the continuum limit, or in the low-energy regime, because in this regime you never have $|\theta_i-\theta_j|\approx\pi$, so small deformations in the value of the $\theta$ field leave the winding number invariant.

Comment: @JahanClaes hmm I see what you're saying, looking at Manton's paper again he defines a discrete fiber bundle but it has a topology connecting the neighboring fibers, which I guess is what is provided by the constraint that $\vert \theta_i - \theta_j\vert$ is always small.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm definitely out of my comfort zone when looking at the discrete bundle papers, but I think the basic intuition makes sense--to define the winding between two neighboring angles, you have to be able to compare them *somehow*, using some sort of connection between them

Comment: @JahanClaes yeah look like this is precisely what this paper is about: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02029132, it's also saying that the field configurations for which small deformations change the winding numbers are measure zero, which makes sense.